# Unity error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (But I think It is)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in unity, I have a hexgrid on the map at runtime. I also have a gameObject, selectedCharacter, that I am trying to write a pathfinding script for. In my grid script, as soon as this line runs, the error pops up. This line of code is in the start() function of the grid Script.

```
selectedCharacter.GetComponent<characterPosition>().hexTile_X = (int) selectedCharacter.transform.position.x;
```

The error is as follows:

> [15:58:06] NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.

The thing is, I have, in the inspector, assigned the selectedCharacter variable to a game object. So I don't understand this error.

The script I'm accessing, characterPosition, is as follows:

`using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class characterPosition : MonoBehaviour
{
  public int hexTile_X, hexTile_Y;
  public gridScript map;

  public List<Node> currentPath = null;

    void Update(){
        if(currentPath != null){
            int curr = 0;

            while(curr < currentPath.Count - 1){
                Vector3 start = map.TileCoordToWorldCoord(currentPath[curr].x, currentPath[curr].y);
                Vector3 end = map.TileCoordToWorldCoord(currentPath[curr+1].x, currentPath[curr+1].y );

                Debug.DrawLine(start, end, Color.yellow);

                curr++;
            }
        }
    }
}`

Thanks.

Comment: _"...Object reference not set to an instance of an object. (But I think It is)"_ -- well, the runtime proves otherwise. Now, you need to figure out why reality doesn't match your incorrect belief about the state of the program. The marked duplicate has lots of detailed advice about how to accomplish that.

Comment: Well if the exception is thrown in `selectedCharacter.GetComponent<characterPosition>().hexTile_X = (int) selectedCharacter.transform.position.x;` then it makes no sense to search the mistake in `characterPosition` ... I'ld rather suspect maybe `selectedCharacter` isn't referenced or it doesn't have the component `characterPosition` attached so `GetComponent` returns `null` ...